# How to set axis properties using a row,column type index on a plotly graph created using make_subplots command

Tags: python, plot, plotly

If I have used the plotly tools command `make_subplots` to make a figure of subplots. How do you set individual axis properties via row, col index scheme?

Once the figure has been created you can add a trace to the figure using row,col index with the append trace command.  Is there a corresponding method for setting other properties of the figure layout like the x or y axis labels?

The `tools.print_grid()` command prints a table of how row,col maps to x,y axis index number.  However it would be nice if there was a command that would return this information.

The only thing I can see to do right now is to access the internal variable:

```
_grid_ref
```

which doesn't seem right.

As an example

```
import plotly.tools as tls
import plotly.plotly as py
from plotly.graph_objs import *

fig = tls.make_subplots(
    rows=3,    
    cols=2,
    shared_xaxes=False,
    shared_yaxes=False,
)

fig.append_trace(Scatter(x=[0,1,2],y=[0,2,4]), 2, 1) #row2 col1
fig.append_trace(Scatter(x=[0,1,2],y=[0,-1,-2]),3,2) #row3 col1

#update the yaxis label for row2, col1
row = 2
col = 1
idx, idy = fig._grid_ref[row-1][col-1]
i = int(idy.lstrip('y'))
fig['layout']['yaxis{}'.format(i)].update(dict(title='positive numbers'))
#update the yaxis label for row3 col1

#update the yaxis label for row2, col1
row = 3
col = 2
idx, idy = fig._grid_ref[row-1][col-1]
i = int(idy.lstrip('y'))
fig['layout']['yaxis{}'.format(i)].update(dict(title='negative numbers'))

py.iplot(fig)
```

If there a better way to do the above that does not rely on visually inspecting the output of `print_grid()`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer*, I work for Plotly.

Unfortunately, there is no other way at the moment to *update* axes generated by `tools.make_subplots`.

I created a github [issue here](https://github.com/plotly/python-api/issues/221). We would love to hear your opinion on this subject.

Comment: The make subplots command specifies rows and columns and how far apart they are which is more convenient than creating all the axes from scratch.  Similarly the add trace command added traces based on row, col location.  So it seems like users should be able to specify everything else about the plot using row, col info.  Failing that it seems like just having a helper function that maps row,col to plot index number would work.  Iterating over a bucket of plots is like in the git hub link is fine provided you know which plot you want to update.  You can conditionally apply formatting